# Latest values based on time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `mydf` below, which I have sorted on a dummy `time` column and the `id`:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
        'time': [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7],
        'val': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
    }
).sort_values(['id', 'time'], ascending=False)

mydf
    id  time    val
5   C   6       f
3   C   5       d
1   B   4       b
2   B   3       c
6   A   7       g
4   A   2       e
0   A   1       a
```

I want to add a column (`last_val`) which, for each unique `id`, holds the latest `val` based on the `time` column. Entries for which there is no `last_val` can be dropped. The output in this example would look like:

```
mydf
    id  time    val last_val
5   C   6       f   d
1   B   4       b   c
6   A   7       g   e
4   A   2       e   a
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `4   A   2       e   a ` correct?

Comment: Yes, `e` is the latest value based on `time`.

Comment: because `for each unique id` - for unique `A` is added 2 rows?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I expressed it badly. I mean for each `id` keep adding the latest value. But I don't want the latest value column to include anything if it means mixing up the `id`. The example output is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) after `sort_values(['id', 'time'], ascending=False)` (already in question) and then remove rows with missing values by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
mydf['last_val'] = mydf.groupby('id')['val'].shift(-1)
mydf = mydf.dropna(subset=['last_val'])
```

Similar solution, only removed last duplicated rows by `id` column:

```
mydf['last_val'] = mydf.groupby('id')['val'].shift(-1)
mydf = mydf[mydf['id'].duplicated(keep='last')]
```

---

```
print (mydf)
  id  time val last_val
5  C     6   f        d
1  B     4   b        c
6  A     7   g        e
4  A     2   e        a
```